# Inner join and full outer join query

Tags: mysql, database

There are four tables

```
Service(Id, AssetId,PlanId)
Plan(Id)
Asset(Id)
NonServiceChargeAsset (ServiceId,AssetId)

Service Table       
Id AssetId  PlanId  
A     a       1  
A     b       1  
A     c       1  
A     d       1  
B     a       2  
B     b       2  
B     c       2  
B     d       2  
C     e       3  
D     f       3  

Asset Table  
Id  
a  
b  
c  
d  
e  
f  

Plan Table  
Id  
1  
2  
3  

NonServiceChargeAsset Table     
ServiceId   AssetId  
A              a  
A              b  
B              c  
B              d  

Output      
ServiceId   AssetId PlanId  
A              c      1  
A              d      1  
B              a      2  
B              b      2  
C              e      3  
D              f      3  


select
    s.*
from
    service s
full outer join
    nonservicechargeAsset ns on s.id = ns.serviceid  
where
    s.assetid not in (select ns.assetid from nonservicechargeasset ns)
```

I could not work out how to use the outer join query to get the result above.

Anyone could assist and advise will be appreciated.

Sorry for the format of the content, if someone can help reformat to help understand the question will be great.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will follow the rule:)

Answer (score 1):

It costs me to understand your goal, but I see that you need all the rows in the service table whose pair **(Id, AssetId)** does not appear in table **NonServiceChargeAsset**. Assuming that, I would do like this:

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM
    Service AS s
LEFT JOIN
    NonServiceChargeAsset AS ns ON ns.ServiceId = s.Id AND ns.AssetId = s.AssetId
WHERE
    ns.AssetId IS NULL AND ns.ServiceId IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it does fix my issue. Great:)

Comment: Good to know it worked, i will appreciate if you can check my answer as correct too.